# Gerando id no input através do foreach

Tags: php, html

estou com dificuldade para gerar um numero em cada id do input. 
Estou precisando exibir 4 imagens, e salvei o nome delas no banco separando por vírgula, depois dei um explode para exibir elas no foreach.

```
$array = explode(',', $sqlImagem['enderecoImagem']);
foreach($array as $valores)
        {
            echo '<a href="#" id="'.$id.'"><img src="Admin/Pagina/Produtos/uploads/'.$valores.'"/></a>';

        }
```

Mas o problema e que preciso montar estilo uma galeria com miniatura, e pra isso preciso gerar um numero(tentei fazer um array, mas não tive sucesso) input id como exemplo acima.

Exemplo do código quando com apenas html, que seria assim que eu preciso...

```
<a href="#" id="1"> <img src="Imagens/teste/k7 sunrace 1.jpg"/> </a>
<a href="#" id="2"> <img src="Imagens/teste/k7 sunrace.jpg"/> </a>
<a href="#" id="3"> <img src="Imagens/teste/k7.jpg"/> </a>
<a href="#" id="4"> <img src="Imagens/teste/k7 sunrace 2.jpg"/> </a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a própria posição da imagem no *array*:

```
foreach($array as $i => $valores) {
    echo "<a href='#' id='imagem_{$i}'><img src='Admin/Pagina/Produtos/uploads/{$valores}'/></a>";
}
```

Assim a saída seria algo como:

```
<a href="#" id="imagem_0"> <img src="Admin/Pagina/Produtos/uploads//k7 sunrace 1.jpg"/> </a>
<a href="#" id="imagem_1"> <img src="Admin/Pagina/Produtos/uploads/k7 sunrace.jpg"/> </a>
<a href="#" id="imagem_2"> <img src="Admin/Pagina/Produtos/uploads//k7.jpg"/> </a>
<a href="#" id="imagem_3"> <img src="Admin/Pagina/Produtos/uploads//k7 sunrace 2.jpg"/> </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para começar pelo numero 1 conforme mostrado na pergunta `<a href="#" id="1">` faça assim:

```
$id=1;
foreach($array as $valores){
    echo '<a href="#" id="'.$id.'"><img src="Admin/Pagina/Produtos/uploads/'.$valores.'"/></a>';

    $id++;
}
```

[exemplo - Ideone](https://ideone.com/RIxaT7)

Ou aproveitando a resposta do Anderson Carlos Woss

```
$i=1;
foreach($array as $valores) {
    echo "<a href=\"#\" id=\"imagem_{$i}\"><img src=\"Admin/Pagina/Produtos/uploads/{$valores}\"/></a>";
    $i++;
}
```

[exemplo Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/22f7a65139ea40f8ef665fc53c9af16bc249639e)